# Scope prepended to name when rendering JavaScriptResourceReference in Wicket 7.0.0-M6

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

In a panel that is supposed to be loading a JS resource, I add a Behavior with the following method to the panel:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response){
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(new
        JavaScriptResourceReference(relativeClass,
        WebApplication.get().getServletContext().getContextPath() +
        jsRef)));
}
```

I can see from stepping through in debug that the name parameter is the context path prepended to the url of the resource, which is exactly what I want! But when the website is run, the panel looks at `localhost:8080/context/scopeURL/context/resourceURL` instead of `localhost:8080/context/resourceURL`. The scope can't be set to null, so what do I have to use for the name parameter to access the resource properly?

Classes are kept in a separate directory structure within the root directory from the scripts that I am trying to load, otherwise this wouldn't be such a problem. Answers which work for Wicket 6.x should work for this version, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScriptResourceReference uses the Class "relativeClass" as a scope and encodes it in the url.

You need to use `ContextRelativeResourceReference(jsRef)`

Comment: Thanks, Martin! I actually was able to render the resource properly with the forUrl method of JavaScriptHeaderItem, obviating creation of a ResourceReference entirely. Is there a reason (other than the additional functionality re: minification) to prefer using forReference(ContextRelativeResourceReference)?